# Jupyter notebook open from cmd at any location or any drive

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, command-prompt, anaconda3

Recently I uninstalled Python and Anaconda. And again reinstalled it. But now I am facing an issue. Previously I was able to open jupyter notebook at any location in any drive by opening Command prompt by typing `cmd` in the address bar but it's now showing the following error:

```
> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How should I handle this now? Please help. I want Jupyter notebook to be open at a specific folder location in a specific drive by opening command prompt through address bar. But not working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably related to your Windows environment variables.

To get to the interface, type the following into a terminal window with admin privileges:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Under 'Path' make sure that your python installation folder is present, if not add it. For me, python is under 'C:\Anaconda' and jupyter under 'C:\Anaconda\Scripts', but that is for an Anaconda installation. For reference see https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#setting-envvars.

To make sure that everything works, type:

```
> where python
> where jupyter
```

You should see the respective installation folders now.